# Javascript: Using super to call parent prototype function inside child prototype function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a question about prototypes and the usage of super in JS.

I have a parent class `Person`. I have hooked a new `toString()` function to `Person.prototype` .

Then, I have a child class `Teacher` (extends `Person`). I am trying to override the `toString()` method on its prototype too, however I would like to reuse the result of the `toString()` method of its parent.

I attempted to call the `toString()` method of the `super` object in the `Teacher` function, but I get an error saying that `super` is undefined.
Why is that?
Is it possible to reuse a method of the parent through super in a prototype function of the super's child?

Now, I'm aware that the issue can be solved in another way, but I'm still curious if it's doable in the manner above.

Here's some reference code:

```js
class Person {
        name;
        email;
        constructor(name, email){
            this.name = name;  
        }
    }
    Person.prototype.toString = function(){
      return `name: ${this.name}`
    }    


    class Teacher extends Person{
        constructor(name, subject){
            super(name);
            this.subject = subject;
        }
    }
    Teacher.prototype.toString = function(){
        return this.super.toString() + ` subject: ${this.subject}`
    }

    let teacher = new Teacher("testname", "testSubject");
    console.log(teacher.toString());
```

Comment: Why are you using the `class` syntax *and* the old-fashioned `.prototype.` syntax together? You usually use one other other. `super()` is part of the `class` syntax only.

Comment: Person.prototype.toString has a typo - it needs to be ```return `name: ${this.name}` ```

Comment: If you wanted to keep the prototype syntax just call `Person.prototype.toString.apply(this)`

Comment: `super` is not dynamically derived from the `this` value, it is derived lexically from the method definition. Put the method inside the `class` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `super` is available when you define a function on the prototype like that. Instead, you should define your methods within the class and use `super.toString`. Like this:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  toString() {
    // you were missing `this` here
    return `name: ${this.name}`;
  }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
  constructor(name, subject) {
    super(name);
    this.subject = subject;
  }
  toString() {
    return super.toString() + ` subject: ${this.subject}`;
  }
}

let teacher = new Teacher("testname", "testSubject");
console.log(teacher.toString());
```